# C++ pointer not null but cannot be freed

Tags: c++, pointers, sigabrt

I'm implementing an open HashTable. My trouble arises in the destructor, where I iterate through all the buckets in an array, for each array I would delete all the nodes in a linked list.

```cpp
        // Deallocate all buckets
        for (int i=0; i<maxBuckets; i++) {
            Cell * p = m_data[i];
            while (p != nullptr) {

                Cell * temp = p;
                p = p->next;
                delete temp;
            }
        }
        delete [] m_data;
```

But it reports `pointer being freed was not allocated` on the delete operation. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Without a [mre] we can't help.

Comment: Maybe you freed the pointer 2 times because your code violates the rule of 3 / 5 / 0 Maybe the pointer is not the same as you allocated because you incremented it.

Comment: I have trouble coming up with one cuz problems seem to emerge when I run my whole project, but nothing goes wrong when I'm isolating the template class and testing it.

Comment: We can give you a few guesses but there is no way to help without guessing.

Comment: `delete temp;` put the value of temp in a log before the delete. When you call new put the returned pointer in the log as well. Make it clear that you are allocating or freeing. Then check the log to verify if you have deleted what you allocated exactly 1 time or more or attempted to delete a pointer that was not allocated. There are tools that can help you debug this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. You tried to `delete` a value that was not returned by `new`.

What we don't know is if the value is the address of a non-allocated value, just uninitialized (garbage) or if you've corrupted the heap. You haven't provided information to determine that.

But you do know that the value you are trying to free is not correct, and you need to figure out where it came from.

Comment: In my initialization i've set all elements of the array m_data to nullptr. Would you take a look at my template class if I were to post the whole thing?

Comment: I gave you a 2 more ideas in my comment to the main question.

Comment: What makes it even more bizzare is that when I test it on a small scale nothing goes wrong, but when I deploy it on a large dataset everything goes haywire

Comment: This is something you will have to solve using a debugger.

Comment: @JohnsonZhou: You need to troubleshoot your code. Write the points you allocate to a log file, and then check them when you're getting ready to free them. Never having seen your code, I can't do very much. Debugging is not always easy.